Open Specific Page in Flutter App on FCM Notification Click When App is Closed
I am developing a Flutter application and using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications. When the app is closed, I want to navigate to a specific page within the app when the user clicks on the FCM notification. Currently, the notification only opens the main page of the app. How can I configure my app to open a particular screen based on the notification data when the app is closed?
import 'dart:developer' as dev;
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_callkit_incoming/entities/entities.dart';
import 'package:flutter_callkit_incoming/flutter_callkit_incoming.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/Routes/generated_routes.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/l10n/support_locale.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/provider/call/call_provider.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/provider/chat/chat_detail_provider.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/provider/home/filter_provider.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/provider/home/lawyer_report_provider.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/provider/localization/localization_provider.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/provider/message/message_list_provider.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/provider/navigation/navigation_provider.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/provider/service/user_service_provider.dart';
import 'package:lawyer/static/call_accept_observer.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

int getUniqueNotificationId() {
  var randomNumber = Random();
  var resultOne = randomNumber.nextInt(2000);
  var resultTwo = randomNumber.nextInt(100);
  if (resultTwo >= resultOne) resultTwo += 1;
  return resultTwo;
}

Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await handleNotification(message);
  return;
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  // await notificationListeners();

  SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
  try {
    sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      null,
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'call_channel',
          channelName: 'Calls',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for calls',
          defaultColor: Colors.orange,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          ledColor: Colors.white,
          channelShowBadge: true,
          playSound: true,
          defaultRingtoneType: DefaultRingtoneType.Ringtone,
          enableLights: true,
          enableVibration: true,
          criticalAlerts: true,
        ),
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'message_channel',
          channelName: 'Messages',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for messages',
          defaultColor: Colors.blue,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          ledColor: Colors.white,
          channelShowBadge: true,
          defaultRingtoneType: DefaultRingtoneType.Notification,
        ),
      ],
    );
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
    print('${FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()}');

    FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen(
      (event) async {
        switch (event!.event) {
          case Event.actionCallIncoming:
            print('Incoming call');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallStart:
            print('Call started');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallAccept:
            print('Call accepted');
            // todo Go named
            try {
              // create a new instance of the provider
              await sharedPrefs.setString('callIncoming', 'Accepted');
              await AppNavigation.rootNavigatorKey.currentState
                  ?.pushNamed('CallExample');
              // Log success or perform additional actions after navigation
            } catch (error, stackTrace) {
              // Handle or log error
              print('Error navigating to CallExample: $error');
              print('StackTrace: $stackTrace');
            }
            return Future.value(true);
          case Event.actionCallDecline:
            print('Call declined');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallEnded:
            print('Call ended');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallTimeout:
            print('Call timeout');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallCallback:
            print('Call callback');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallToggleHold:
            print('Call hold toggled');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallToggleMute:
            print('Call mute toggled');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallToggleDmtf:
            print('Call DMTF toggled');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallToggleGroup:
            print('Call group toggled');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallToggleAudioSession:
            print('Call audio session toggled');
            break;
          case Event.actionDidUpdateDevicePushTokenVoip:
            print('Device push token updated');
            break;
          case Event.actionCallCustom:
            print('Custom call action');
            break;
          default:
            print('Unknown event type ${event.event}');
        }
      },
    );

  } catch (error, stackTrace) {
    print('Error getting shared preferences: $error');
    print('StackTrace: $stackTrace');

    // Optionally initialize sharedPrefs with a default/fallback value if necessary
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Future<void> handleNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  String? title = message.data['title'] ?? 'Default Title';
  String? body = message.data['body'] ?? 'Default Body';
  String channelKey = message.data['channel_key'] ?? 'default_channel';

  if (channelKey == 'call_channel') {
    // await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    //   content: NotificationContent(
    //     id: getUniqueNotificationId(),
    //     channelKey: channelKey,
    //     color: Colors.white,
    //     title: title,
    //     body: body,
    //     category: NotificationCategory.Call,
    //     wakeUpScreen: true,
    //     fullScreenIntent: true,
    //     autoDismissible: false,
    //     backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    //   ),
    //   actionButtons: [
    //     NotificationActionButton(
    //       key: 'ACCEPT',
    //       label: 'Accept Call',
    //       color: Colors.green,
    //       autoDismissible: true,
    //       enabled: true,
    //     ),
    //     NotificationActionButton(
    //       key: 'REJECT',
    //       label: 'Reject Call',
    //       color: Colors.redAccent,
    //       autoDismissible: true,
    //     ),
    //   ],
    // );

    CallKitParams params = const CallKitParams(
        id: "21232dgfgbcbgb",
        nameCaller: "Coding Is Life",
        appName: "Demo",
        avatar: "https://i.pravata.cc/100",
        handle: "123456",
        type: 0,
        textAccept: "Accept",
        textDecline: "Decline",
        duration: 30000,
        extra: {'userId': "sdhsjjfhuwhf"},
        missedCallNotification: NotificationParams(
            callbackText: "Call back", showNotification: false),
        android: AndroidParams(
            isCustomNotification: true,
            isShowLogo: false,
            ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
            backgroundColor: "#0955fa",
            backgroundUrl: "https://i.pravata.cc/500",
            actionColor: "#4CAF50",
            incomingCallNotificationChannelName: "Incoming call",
            missedCallNotificationChannelName: "Missed call"),
        ios: IOSParams(
            iconName: "Call Demo",
            handleType: 'generic',
            supportsVideo: true,
            maximumCallGroups: 2,
            maximumCallsPerCallGroup: 1,
            audioSessionMode: 'default',
            audioSessionActive: true,
            audioSessionPreferredSampleRate: 44100.0,
            audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration: 0.005,
            supportsDTMF: true,
            supportsHolding: true,
            supportsGrouping: false,
            ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default'));
    await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);
  } else if (channelKey == 'message_channel') {
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: getUniqueNotificationId(),
        channelKey: channelKey,
        color: Colors.blue,
        title: title,
        body: body,
        category: NotificationCategory.Message,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        autoDismissible: true,
      ),
      actionButtons: [
        NotificationActionButton(
          key: 'READ',
          label: 'Read Message',
          color: Colors.green,
          autoDismissible: true,
        ),
        NotificationActionButton(
          key: 'DISMISS',
          label: 'Dismiss',
          color: Colors.red,
          autoDismissible: true,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  // await notificationListeners();

  return;
}

Future<void> notificationListeners() async {
  await AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
    onActionReceivedMethod: (ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
      dev.log('Action Received: ${receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed}');
      String? newTitle;
      String? newBody;

      if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed == 'ACCEPT') {
        print('ForgotPassword');
        Navigator.of(GlobalKey<NavigatorState>().currentContext!)
            .pushNamed('ForgotPassword');
        Navigator.pushNamed(
            GlobalKey<NavigatorState>().currentContext!, '/forgotPassword');
        BuildContext context = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>().currentContext!;
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('ForgotPassword');
        print('-->ForgotPassword');
        newTitle = 'Call Accepted';
        newBody = 'You have accepted the call.';
      } else if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed == 'REJECT') {
        newTitle = 'Call Rejected';
        newBody = 'You have rejected the call.';
      } else if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed == 'READ') {
        newTitle = 'Message Read';
        newBody = 'You have read the message.';
      } else if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed == 'DISMISS') {
        newTitle = 'Message Dismissed';
        newBody = 'You have dismissed the message.';
      } else {
        dev.log('Unknown Action');
        newTitle = 'Unknown Action';
        newBody = 'An unknown action was taken.';
      }

      await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
          id: getUniqueNotificationId(),
          channelKey: 'response_channel',
          color: Colors.purple,
          title: newTitle,
          body: newBody,
          backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
          autoDismissible: true,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}

Future<void> callKit() async {}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({
    super.key,
    this.logTitle = 'call accept  defoult ',
  });

  String? logTitle;

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('MyApp build');
    print(widget.logTitle);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => FilterProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => MessageListProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ChatDetailProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => LawyerReportProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserServiceProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CallProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CallAcceptProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NavigationProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => LocalizationProvider())
      ],
      child: Consumer<LocalizationProvider>(
        builder: (context, provider, child) {
          return MaterialApp.router(
            color: Color(0xFF000E2B),
            title: 'Lawyer',
            localizationsDelegates: const [
              AppLocalizations.delegate, // Add this line
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            locale: provider.locale,
            supportedLocales: L10n.support,
            routerConfig: AppNavigation.router,
            theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'SF-Pro-Display',
              primarySwatch: Colors.green,
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF000E2B),
                elevation: 0,
                iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              bottomSheetTheme: const BottomSheetThemeData(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3467E4),
              ),
              tabBarTheme: const TabBarTheme(),
              checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
                side: BorderSide.none,
                checkColor: const WidgetStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
                fillColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                  (Set<WidgetState> states) {
                    if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
                      return const Color.fromRGBO(59, 118, 81, 1);
                    }
                    return const Color.fromRGBO(152, 152, 152, 1);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CallExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const CallExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Call pAGE sTART');
    return MaterialApp(builder: (context, child) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Call Example'),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

